# Como resolver este erro de referencia de um objeto?

Tags: c#, webforms

ao compilar a aplicação para gerar meu relatório, estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha 550, é referente a esse pedaço do meu código que começa no if:

```
if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao == 0 && movimentacao.Cotacao == null && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador == null)
            {
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, SigIndicador, valorCotacao, datacotacao, username, data));
            }
```

E logo abaixo eu tenho o código por completo:

```
#region Validação de cotação caso seja nula ou vazia[+===================================================+]
            if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao == 0 && movimentacao.Cotacao == null && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador == null)
            {
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, SigIndicador, valorCotacao, datacotacao, username, data));
            }
            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao != 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador == null && movimentacao.Cotacao == null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, SigIndicador, movimentacao.ValorCotacao, datacotacao, username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao == 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador != null && movimentacao.Cotacao != null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador.SigIndicador, valorCotacao, movimentacao.Cotacao.DatCotacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao == 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador == null && movimentacao.Cotacao != null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, SigIndicador, valorCotacao, movimentacao.Cotacao.DatCotacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao != 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador != null && movimentacao.Cotacao == null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador, movimentacao.ValorCotacao, datacotacao, username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao != 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador == null && movimentacao.Cotacao != null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, SigIndicador, movimentacao.ValorCotacao, movimentacao.Cotacao.DatCotacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao == 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador != null && movimentacao.Cotacao == null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador.SigIndicador, valorCotacao, datacotacao, username, data));

            else if (movimentacao.ValorCotacao != 0 && movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador != null && movimentacao.Cotacao != null)
                strConstrution.Append(string.Format(rodape, movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador.SigIndicador, movimentacao.ValorCotacao, movimentacao.Cotacao.DatCotacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), username, data));

            #endregion
```

Existe uma maneira de corrigir esse problema no meu caso? Postei o código para melhor visualizar.

Comment: Maniero, as sugestões apresentado por você não ajuda na solução dos meus problemas apresentados acima.

Comment: ajuda sim, o erro é o mesmo, simplesmente você está tentando acessar um objeto que não foi instânciado... o que acontece se você faz `movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Indicador` mas o `ContratoOperCred` é nulo, ou seja, não é instânciado ?... ou então se o próprio objeto `movimentacao` for nulo... você precisa fazer essas verificações... e pode usar apenas um ? pra isso.... `movimentacao?.ContratoOperCred?.Indicador == null`